# Searching matching strings in 2 lists does not work at all

Tags: python, django

I am developing a specific feature for a website (using Django) and I need to compare 2 lists of strings.

The first list contains some required identificators and the second one contains some other identificators.

I have to verify which id from the first list is missing in the second one, doing this:

```
def mods_checker(request):
html = request.POST["text"]

all_mods = Mod.objects.exclude(deprecated=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
links = soup.find_all('a', {'data-type': 'Link'})
ids = []
all_ids = []
missing_mods = []

for l in links:
    ids.append(get_id(l.text))

for m in all_mods:
    all_ids.append(m.get_id())

print ids
print all_ids

for m in all_mods:
    if m.get_id not in ids:
        missing_mods.append(m.name)

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(missing_mods))
```

(Sorry for the indentation, of course everything is ok in my editor)

I know that this piece of code is redundant, I did it to do some checks and some debug prints.

The problem is that I get a wrong set of ids (all of them, more specifically) and I don't know why.

Every check I did in python editor with test data is ok. What am I doing wrong?

Every print is fine and I get all ids correctly.

Comment: Why do you create the variable all_ids if you never use it?

Comment: I just created it to print and check its content

Comment: Ah, in that case its always best to remove it when you post your question. Try to achieve a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: You're right, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`if m.get_id not in ids` cannot be `True` because you're testing if the *function* is in your list, not the result (as did correctly above).

You have to actually *call* it for it to work using parentheses:

```
if m.get_id() not in ids:
```

Aside: if you want to speed up that lookup code, consider creating a `set` for `ids`

```
ids = {get_id(l.text) for l in links}
```

Comment: Wow, I did such a noob error there :D Thanks a lot mate! Anyway I tried and now I have to solve another bug (which is related to the URL parsing library, so nothing to worry about) but I think it will work! Once I'll have tried, I will tell you how it goes!